# Replaces all of these words except those in the img and h2 tags

Tags: jquery

I have jquery to convert words into links. This code successfully blocks words contained in image tags.
But I still have a problem, the word is still a link when inside h1,h2,h3 and other tags.

Can the jquery code replace only the words contained in the `p tag`?

**my code:**

```
    var myCat = ['ABC', 'Hoo'],
        goUrl = new RegExp('(?<!<img[^>]*?)(' + myCat.join('|') + ')', 'g');

    jQuery('.post-body').html(function (_, curHtml) {
        return curHtml.replace(goUrl, "<a href='/search/label/$1'>$1</a>");
    });
```

or maybe there is a better way without jquery, so just using javascript, it will be better for me.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your requirements but if you want to limit the replacements to only the texts within the `p` tags. You can modify the jQuery to target only those elements;

**jQuery Example**

```js
var myCat = ['ABC', 'Hoo'],
    goUrl = new RegExp('(?<!<img[^>]*?)(' + myCat.join('|') + ')', 'g');

jQuery('.post-body p').html(function (_, curHtml) {
    return curHtml.replace(goUrl, "<a href='/search/label/$1'>$1</a>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="post-body">
    <h1>Here is a header with ABC</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph with ABC</p>
    <h2>Here is another header with Hoo</h2>
    <p>This is another paragraph with Hoo</p>
    <img src="https://example.com/image.jpg" alt="This is an image with alt text ABC and Hoo">
</div>
```

**JavaScript Only Example**

```js
var myCat = ['ABC', 'Hoo'],
    goUrl = new RegExp('(?<!<img[^>]*?)(' + myCat.join('|') + ')', 'g');

document.querySelectorAll('.post-body p').forEach(function(element) {
    element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(goUrl, "<a href='/search/label/$1'>$1</a>");
});
```

```html
<div class="post-body">
    <h1>Here is a header with ABC</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph with ABC</p>
    <h2>Here is another header with Hoo</h2>
    <p>This is another paragraph with Hoo</p>
    <img src="https://example.com/image.jpg" alt="This is an image with alt text ABC and Hoo">
</div>
```